# R function cdplot: Why are the factor levels flipped on some computers?

Tags: r

Just stumbled over a very weird behaviour of the R function `cdplot`. When I call the following code on Linux, it yields the conditional density plot for the factor level "1":

```
> x <- 1:10
> y <- factor(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))
> res <- cdplot(x,y)
> print(res)
$`1`
```

Whereas the same code on MaOS X yields the complementary density plot, i.e. of level "0":

```
> print(res)
$`0`
```

Is there some way to reliably obtain a density plot for a specific factor level? If not: Is there a simpler way to figure out which density `cdplot` computes, other than calling `names(unlist(res))` and comparing it with the elements in `levels(y)`?

Comment: Are you running different versions of R? Note that the behavior of `cdplot` changed in version 4.0.0. You can find that announcement on the https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html page if you search for "cdplot". It's likely that one of your R versions is <4.0 and the other is >=4.0

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. This is the problem. Why on earth did they change this? I am now trying to implement a way to automatically conclude this from the return value of cdplot.

Comment: @MrFlick I have elaborated your comment into an answer which also provides a general solution, so that the question can be closed as "answered".

Comment: @MrFlick Just noted that (theoretically!) the `cdplot` argument `ylevels` should control the order of the levels plotted, but, alas, this argument was flipped around too with R version 4.0. Arrrgh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MrFlick for pointing to the change in the behaviour of `cdplot` between R versions 3 and 4:

> The default order of the levels on the y-axis for `spineplot()` and `cdplot()` has been reversed.

A simple workaround that works with any R version is to add the missing level to the conditional density function as follows:

```
missing.level <- levels(y)[which(names(res) != levels(y))]
res[[missing.level]] <- function(v) {1 - res[[1]](v)}
```

That way, `res[[factorlevel]](x)` can return the conditional probability *P(y=factorlevel|x)* for all values of the factor level.

If there are more than two levels, the function in the last line must be replaced by one minus the sum over all remaining levels, of course.